# Bypass truncated data type error in `CREATE TABLE AS`

Tags: mariadb, hierarchy, tree, mariadb-10.2

I am attempting to recreate the code from [this excellent tutorial](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/) in MariaDB 10.2 to try and build nested sets from an existing adjacency list. (The goal being to ingest changes to the adjacency list one at a time and then rebuild the nested sets at certain time intervals).

However, I've hit a snag with this bit:

```
SortPath =  CAST(
                    CAST(anchor.EmployeeID AS BINARY(4)) 
                AS VARBINARY(4000)) --Up to 1000 levels deep.
```

I've switched it to this:

```
CAST(CAST(anchor.EmployeeID AS BINARY(4)) AS BINARY(4000)) AS sort_path ## Also with 8000
```

I also tried `CAST(anchor.EmployeeID AS Binary(4)) AS sort_path`

All approaches have thus far yielded a variant of this error message:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1\x00\x00\x00'
```

**EDIT**

The full sql statement being run is this:

```
##===== Conditionally drop Temp tables to make reruns easy
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hierarchy;

##===== Build the new table on-the-fly including some place holders
CREATE TABLE hierarchy AS

WITH RECURSIVE cteBuildPath AS 
( ##=== This is the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE.
     ## The only thing it does is load the Root Node.
 SELECT anchor.tree_user_id, 
        anchor.upline_id, 
        1 AS hlevel,
        CAST(anchor.tree_user_id AS BINARY(4)) AS sort_path ##Up to 1000 levels deep.
  FROM example.tree AS anchor
  WHERE upline_id IS NULL ##Only the Root Node has a NULL ManagerID
  UNION ALL 
 ##==== This is the "recursive" part of the CTE that adds 1 for each level
     ## and concatenates each level of EmployeeID's to the SortPath column.  
 SELECT recur.tree_user_id, 
        recur.upline_id, 
        cte.HLevel + 1,
        cte.sort_path + CAST(recur.tree_user_id AS BINARY(4))
   FROM example.tree AS recur
  INNER JOIN cteBuildPath AS cte 
          ON cte.tree_user_id = recur.upline_id
) ##=== This final SELECT/INTO creates the Node # in the same order as a
     ## push-stack would. It also creates the final table with some
     ## "reserved" columns on the fly. We'll leave the SortPath column in
     ## place because we're still going to need it later.
     ## The ISNULLs make NOT NULL columns.
 SELECT IFNULL(sorted.tree_user_id,0) AS tree_user_id,
        sorted.upline_id,
        IFNULL(sorted.hlevel,0) AS hlevel,
      #  IFNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0) AS left_bower, ##Place holder
      #  IFNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0) AS right_bower, ##Place holder
      (@n := @n + 1) AS node_number,
      #  IFNULL(CAST(0 AS INT),0) AS node_count, ##Place holder
        IFNULL(sorted.sort_path,sorted.sort_path) AS sort_path
   FROM cteBuildPath AS sorted
   JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) n ON 1=1
   #ORDER BY sorted.sort_path
 #OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100) ##Change this IF necessary
;
```

What is the correct way to duplicate the desired logic in MariaDB 10.2?

Comment: I'm not sure where the `double` is coming from ....? BINARY(4) is four bytes, so can store an INT, but not a BIGINT. What is the data type of `example.tree.tree_user_id`? Maybe try BINARY(8) or BINARY(16) instead, just to be sure. (And in both the places you use `CAST`.)

Answer (score 1):

After much googling, I came to realize that the error message was exactly correct though somewhat vague.

`Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1\x00\x00\x00'` meant that somewhere in my query, my `CAST BINARY` was being converted back to a `DOUBLE` data type.

Once I figured that out, re-reading the query made me consider how this little gem was working: `cte.sort_path + CAST(recur.tree_user_id AS BINARY(4))`. Turns out, based on a small sample query that the `BINARY` value was being converted so addition could be performed.

Switching to `CONCAT(cte.sort_path, CAST(recur.tree_user_id AS BINARY(8)))` appears to have corrected the problem.